# Isnt' it possible to run OpenGL 3.0 on Macbok Pro 2015 mid with glfw3?

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I want to run OpenGL 3.0 or OpenGL ES on Macbook Pro 2015 mid(Intel Iris Pro Graphics).

When I specify `glfwWindowHint` below, the error occurs and stop running.

```
// Initialise GLFW
if( !glfwInit() ) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    getchar();
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

The error is:

```
Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.
```

Do you know how to run OpenGL 3.0 with glfw3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to extend a bit on the accepted answer, and try to answer your actual question:

> Do you know how to run OpenGL 3.0 with glfw3?

You *can't*. Because OSX simply does not implement it.

What OSX does implement is the core profile of modern OpenGL, which was *invented* with OpenGL 3.2. Furthermore, OSX also implements OpenGL 2.1 as *legacy* OpenGL to ensure compatibility with existing applications.

Since the changes of the OpenGL 3.2 core profile are not backward compatible, there were mechanisms added so that an application can request a specific GL version and profile. Legacy applications which do know nothing about that profiles, and the non-compatible changes of modern GL, will request a GL context as they always did - and will end up with at most GL 2.1 on OSX.

If you want to use modern GL on OSX, you have to explicitely request a (forward-compatible) core profile (and as per the spec, implementors are only required to implement the core profile, the compatibility profile is optional, so OSX is conformant to the GL spec). GLFW can do this for you, but:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

cannot possibly work in a meaningful way. You are requesting an OpenGL 3.0 core profile *which does not even exist*. When requesting a GL version before profiles were introduced. the profile request will just be ignored, and you will be getting some GL context of at least the requested version, or a higher one, *which is compatible to the one you requested*. Since OSX's legacy GL can't fullfill 3.0, and since the modern 3.2 core is incompatible to 3.0, you get no GL context at all...

You either have to request something <= 2.1, to get a legacy context, or you have to request at least 3.2 core (+forwad compatibility) to get modern OpenGL on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

Might be the specific version you are targeting. Any reason not to target 3.3?

I'm running GLFW3 just fine on my MacBook Pro (late 2014, also Iris Pro) using these window hints:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree with you. I can also run OpenGL 3.3 on my Macbook Pro. But I just want to run version 3.0 or GL ES 3.0. Because I plan to transplant it to OpenGL ES 3.0 ...

Comment: Might be an issue with GLFW. You should consider posting it on [github](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues); they might have an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I found the related commit.

https://github.com/glfw/glfw/commit/fd127d59fa71a4b38b8d5b4e9f2ef804443fa2b1

I don't know why it can not run 3.1 and lower version on Mac...

Comment: OpenGL ES 3.0 has nothing to do with OpenGL 3.0. It is kind of similar to OpenGL 4.3 Core Profile.